# bbPress redirecting with php code

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

Hello I want to redirect to my page to user page right now i write code inside wordpress page
this code for redirecting me to `example.com/*userid*`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/members/<?php 
$id = bbp_get_user_id();

?>/?user='.$id/">
```

Where am I actually making mistake

Comment: The .$id is outside the PHP block.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can't type PHP into a WordPress post/page contents for security reasons. Additionally, `<meta>` tags belong in the header, not in a post body.

Comment: is there any alternative ways?